# HTML button onclick performs action on other HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

It is a simple problem but I cannot get around it as I am new to angular and web development. Basically there are two components home and dashboard. The button in home.component.html changes the source of the image from bulbOn.png to bulbOff.png. I want that the same button should also change the source similarly also on dashboard.component.html. I think I need to use typescript for that but I dont know how. Basically how should onClick on one html performs actions on other html?

home.component.html

```
<mat-card >              
              <button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='assets/BulbOn.svg'">Turn on the bulb.</button>
              
              <img id="myImage" src="assets/BulbOn.svg" style="width:100px">
              
              <button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='assets/BulbOff.svg'">Turn off the bulb.</button>
              
              </mat-card>
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<mat-card class="bulbCard">
    <div class="bulbimg"> <img src="assets/BulbOn.svg"> </div>
    </mat-card>
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.less']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '@app/_models';
import { AccountService } from '@app/_services';

@Component({ templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.less'] })
export class HomeComponent {
    user: User;

    constructor(private accountService: AccountService) {
        this.user = this.accountService.userValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid manipulating the DOM like this with Angular.

And instead of using onclick, you should use Angulars event bindings. https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

```
<mat-card>              
    <button (click)="changeBulbState(true)">
        Turn on the bulb.
    </button>
              
    <img [src]="bulbState ? 'assets/BulbOn.svg' : 'assets/BulbOff.svg'" style="width:100px">
              
    <button (click)="changeBulbState(false)">
        Turn off the bulb.
    </button>
              
</mat-card>
```

Within your component's typescript add a variable for bulbState. The value of which will be changed when you interact with the buttons in your card.

The src of the image will change depending on if the bulbState variable is true or false.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '@app/_models';
import { AccountService } from '@app/_services';

@Component({ templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.less'] })
export class HomeComponent {
    user: User;

    bulbState: boolean;

    constructor(
        private accountService: AccountService,
        private bulbStatusService: BulbStatusService
    ) {
        this.user = this.accountService.userValue,
        this.bulbStatusService.bulbStatus.subscribe(data => this.bulbState = value)
    }

    changeBulbState(state: boolean) {
        this.bulbStatusService.changeBulbState(state);
    }

}
```

In order to share this across multiple components I would suggest using a service.

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/sharing-data-between-angular-components-f76fa680bf76

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class BulbStatusService {

  private bulbState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  bulbStatus = this.bulbState.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeBulbState(state: boolean) {
    this.bulbState.next(state)
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I tried it doing the way you explained using the boolean variable but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I have refactored it to show you how to use a service to control the state and share it between components. You will need to add the bulbStatusService to your dashboard component as well and subscribe to it's changes.

Answer (score 0):

What you would like to is to have a bulb state somewhere. Usually in Angular it's either the parent component which passes the state down to it's children or you can have a service to get/set the state. RxJS comes bundled with Angular and has some great utilities (observables) for sharing the state.

e.g. app-state.service.ts

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppState {
   public readonly lightBulb = new BehaviorSubject<'on' | 'off'>('on');
}
```

Now inject this to you home component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '@app/_models';
import { AccountService } from '@app/_services';
import { AppState } from 'app-state.service';

@Component({ templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.less'] })
export class HomeComponent {
    user: User;

    constructor(
        private accountService: AccountService,
        public state: AppState
    ) {
        this.user = this.accountService.userValue;
    }
}
```

In HTML:

```
<mat-card>              
  <button (click)="state.lightBulb.next('on')">Turn on the bulb.</button>
  <img id="myImage" [src]="(state.lightBulb | async) === 'on' ? 'assets/BulbOn.svg' : 'assets/BulbOff.svg'" style="width:100px">
  <button (click)="state.lightBulb.next('off')">Turn off the bulb.</button>
</mat-card>
```

Then do the same thing for dashboard component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppState } from 'app-state.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.less']
})
export class DashboardComponent {

  constructor(public state: AppState) { }
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<mat-card class="bulbCard">
    <div class="bulbimg"><img [src]="(state.lightBulb | async) === 'on' ? 'assets/BulbOn.svg' : 'assets/BulbOff.svg'"></div>
</mat-card>
```

So in the nut shell, `Subject`s are things that holds some value and that value can be changed with `Subject.next([value here])`.

`Subject`s are `Observable`s and `Observable`s can be `subscribe`d to to get those values over time. In Angular we have `async` pipe which does this subscription for you and disposes that as well after the component is destroyed.

There are few things you could do better with this "observable store pattern" but here it is at it's simplest form.

Few notes related to other things: use `(click)` instead `onclick` as `()` is the Angular's way to bind outputs. Don't directly manipulate (or at least avoid) anything in DOM e.g. ´document.getElementById('myImage').src='assets/BulbOn.svg'´ but rather bind a value for that attribute with `[]` e.g. `[bulbSvgSource]` where ´bulbSvgSource´ would be defined in the component class.

Comment: I think this is the solution I am looking for but I am getting some error in  app-state.service.ts. I generated the service but it says the following thing and I am too noob to understand it -  (alias) new BehaviorSubject<unknown>(_value: unknown): BehaviorSubject<unknown>
import BehaviorSubject
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
BehaviorSubject.d.ts(12, 17): An argument for '_value' was not provided.
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'BehaviorSubject<unknown>'

Comment: was it because a typo I had in new BehaviorSubject<'on' | 'off'>('on');?
should be new BehaviorSubject<'on' | 'off''>('on');